# Uninstall AFNetworking from Xcode Workspace

Tags: xcode, afnetworking, uninstallation

Can somebody help me uninstall/remove AFNetworking from my xcode project? I have tried deleting the files, but then I recieve an error message.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to delete all thing on Podfile archive and then install the pod again with the command "pod install" on the worksapce path.

It worked to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Cocoapods,
1. Remove the line

```
pod 'AFNetworking'
```

from Podfile.
2. Open terminal, go to project directory, & do

```
 pod install
```

That should work.

And,
If you're not using Cocoapods, just remove the AFNetworking framework from XcodeProject file.

Comment: There is no such AFNetworking pod in the project still showing frameworks